# How to go to the previous page dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

i'm very new to Jquery/Jquery Mobile.I'm trying to get the previous page dynamically using jquery. I tried but its not working properly can anyone help me out from this problem.

My code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SP6ww/8/)

When i click on the `Next & Prev` buttons its working fine for the first time but when i'm again do the same for the second time "prev" button is working fine "Next" button is not working it automatically going to next links and also the file is not loading for the first time.

Can anyone help me to work this properly.

Thanks in Advance.

**Updated question:**

Tiles is also like a grid view but tiles somewhat different than grid.

In this picture is a grid view like this only but in tiles we wont show all the titles at a time.

For example:consider this image we have A to F titles here using grid view.consider same in tiles also we have A to F titles we show the titles depends on the screen size. if we have more than A to F titles then we have "one button" its displays the count of titles we have.When we click on this then it has to open the other remaining titles.

Comment: check this, I have made some modifications to my old jsfiddle. Now, once you click on any main section (3 sections) it will create separate pages for each list view item, then you can navigate between them freely. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CU9Tc/

Comment: some problem is there i updated this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q78jY/ with code for loading file but first time my file is not loading second its working fine and another problem is when i'm click on 1st parent link next i click on 2nd parent link and again if i select the 1st parent and continue click on the next i'm getting 2nd parent childs also..

Comment: check this now, all files are loaded. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CU9Tc/

Comment: working fine but another problem is when i suddenly clicked on the "the touch of love" and came back clicking on the "seduce partner" getting the child tags by clicking on "next" along with the "the touch of love" child tags.

Comment: i've fixed this just now ;) click on next/prev and see ;) now you need to add home button somewhere.

Comment: sorry omar..its working fine i have checked the previous one..is there any way to hide the next button if page is last page then next button should be hide in place of alert

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CU9Tc/

Comment: great, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Omar now this demo is with listview.Can we make this demo view with tiles..?

Comment: Omar, i had updated my question above..check this

Comment: It is better to post it in a different question. This will mix things up.

Comment: ok..can you understand my question ?

Comment: yes but i think we can make this in grid view but i dont know how in this tiles.

Comment: yes,but i think you understand my question right.Omar i'm very new to using this one how to i accept your ?

Comment: post a new question with the code so i can check it. there's a mark underneath up/down buttons. check it and that's it :)

Comment: Tell me what do u need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move between pages using `$.mobile.changePage()` and by retrieving `[data-role=page]` id of previous `.prev()` and next `.next()` pages.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CU9Tc/)**

**Create pages dynamically**

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#chapter', function () {
 var length = $('#chapter [data-role=listview] li a').length;
 $('#chapter [data-role=listview] li a').each(function (i) {
  var file = $(this).attr('file');
  var content = $(this).text();
  var seq = $(this).data('sequence');
  if ($('[data-role=page]#' + seq).length === 0) {
   $($.mobile.pageContainer).append('<div data-role="page" id="' + seq + '" class="listitems"><div data-role="header"><a href="#" data-role="button" class="prev" data-icon="arrow-l">Prev</a><h1 id="header2">' + content + '</h1><a href="#" data-role="button" class="next" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a></div><div data-role="content"></div><div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a></div></div>');
   $('[data-role=page]#' + seq + ' [data-role=content]').load(file);
   if (i === 0) {
    $('[data-role=page]#' + seq).addClass('first');
   }
   if (length == (i + 1)) {
    $('[data-role=page]#' + seq).addClass('last');
   }
  }
 });
});


$(document).on('click', '#chapter [data-role=listview] li a', function () {
 var goto = '#' + $(this).data('sequence');
 $.mobile.changePage(goto);
});
```

**Navigation**

```
// Next page
$(document).on('click', '.next', function () {
 var next = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(next, {
    transition: 'slide'
 });
});

// Previous page
$(document).on('click', '.prev', function () {
 var prev = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prev('[data-role=page]')[0].id;
 $.mobile.changePage(prev, {
    transition: 'slide',
    reverse: true
 });
});
```

**Show/Hide navigation buttons**

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page].listitems', function () {
 if ($(this).hasClass('first')) {
  $('.prev').hide();
  $('.next').show();
 } 
 else if ($(this).hasClass('last')) {
  $('.prev').show();
  $('.next').hide();
 }
 else {
  $('.next, .prev').show();
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying..Omar but its not between the different pages..its between the single page "#words" i'm just different loading the file in this pages.If you see the above fiddle you can get. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @user2384323 i have worked on this fiddle before, i need to refresh my memory. it seems that event is being fired twice. let me check

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var referrer =  document.referrer;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but can you check my code once and where i did the mistake.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

This will work. :)

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button">Go back</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying...i already use this one in my code.can you check the above code in fiddle.Thnaks in Advance.

Comment: `if (nextlink != null) {
                $(nextlink).**find('a').click()**;
            }`     I guess, there is an error. It is firing an automatic click when `nextlink` is not null and moving it to next link (I am not fully sure about it, it is just based on my understanding)

Comment: before i add "Prev" button its working fine see this:http://jsfiddle.net/SP6ww/5/